# CUDA string search in large file, wrong result

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I am working on simple naive string search in CUDA.

I am new in CUDA. It works fine fol smaller files ( aprox. ~1MB ). After I make these files bigger ( ctrl+a ctrl+c several times in notepad++ ), my program's results are higher ( about +1% ) than a

```
 grep -o text file_name | wc -l
```

It is very simple function, so I don't know what could cause this. I need it to work with larger files ( ~500MB ).

Kernel code ( **`gpuCount`** is a `__device__ int global variable` ):

```
__global__ void stringSearchGpu(char *data, int dataLength, char *input, int inputLength){ 
     int id = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
     if (id < dataLength)
     {
         int fMatch = 1;
         for (int j = 0; j < inputLength; j++)
         {
            if (data[id + j] != input[j]) fMatch = 0;
         }
         if (fMatch)
         {
             atomicAdd(&gpuCount, 1);
         }
     }
 }
```

This is calling the kernel in main function:

```
    int blocks = 1, threads = fileSize;

    if (fileSize > 1024)
    {
        blocks = (fileSize / 1024) + 1;
        threads = 1024;
    }

    clock_t cpu_start = clock();
    // kernel call
    stringSearchGpu<<<blocks, threads>>>(cudaBuffer, strlen(buffer), cudaInput, strlen(input));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

After this I just copy the result to Host and print it.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should always check return values of CUDA functions to check for errors. Best way to do so would be the following:

```
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}
```

Wrap your CUDA calls, such as:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

Second, your kernel accesses out of bounds memory. Suppose, `dataLength=100`, `inputLength=7` and `id=98`. In your kernel code:

```
if (id < dataLength) // 98 is less than 100, so condition true
     {
         int fMatch = 1;
         for (int j = 0; j < inputLength; j++) // j runs from [0 - 6]
         {
            // if j>1 then id+j>=100, which is out of bounds, illegal operation
            if (data[id + j] != input[j]) fMatch = 0;
         }
```

Change the condition to something like:

```
if (id < dataLength - inputLength)
```

Comment: thanks for the peeks, but this did not help with my original problem

Comment: @MiroslavProcházka Post your modified, complete code.

Comment: @MiroslavProcházka Post the file for which this code gives incorrect results.

Comment: @MiroslavProcházka Your code gives consistent results for me.

Comment: and you compared results with `grep -o text test.txt | wc -l` ? I am running it on VS 2015 with CUDA Version 9.0.176

Comment: I am running it for example with string: "_of_" and my code gives me result: 7324 and grep gives me: 7232.

Comment: that is because when I insert the input I need to confirm it with an Enter key, that adds a newline there, so I need to delete it. I changed the code and the result of searching "_of_" is: 562.

Comment: @MiroslavProcházka Oh, I edited your code and forgot about `stdin` input. For me output of `of` is 7232, whether I get input in console or I hardcode it.

Comment: is it possible that I am using MS Windows and Visual studio and encoding of file is ANSI? Or I don't know what could be the problem

Comment: @MiroslavProcházka You can change encoding in notepad, see if it has any affects.